# App is crashing due to connections left open. Should I close them in the DAL, or in the domain repositories?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that was running fine in dev & test but is crashing under load. The culprit is failure to close the `OdbcConnection`s that I'm using in a custom DAL. The underlying database is Oracle. Entity Framework was not an option at the time this project started so we have a custom DAL to centralize all access to the Oracle database. The DAL is just a POCO that wraps the connection and has a couple of helper methods to wrap `QueryReader` and `ExecuteNonQuery` for convenience. The DAL is used by a set of domain repositories (over a dozen) that in turn build domain models by querying the DAL.

**My question: Where should I close the connection in this scenario?**

For example, in the DAL I have a method that gets the connection based on the environment in which the app is hosted:

```
public OdbcConnection GetConnection()
{
    // environment check happens, then return
    return new OdbcConnection(myConnectionString);
}
```

Then I have methods like this in the DAL:

```
public OdbcCommand CreateCommand(string queryText)
{
    return new OdbcCommand(queryText);
}

public OdbcDataReader QueryReader(string queryText)
{
    var connection = GetConnection();
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = queryText;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        return QueryReader(command);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}

public OdbcDataReader QueryReader(OdbcCommand command)
{
    var connection = GetConnection();
    connection.Open;
    try
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Prepare();
        return command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

(the try/finally blocks were added as a first attempt to stop the errors, but closing the connection here breaks all the repositories, as seen below)

Then my repository methods look something like this:  (`_dal` is a protected object loaded by the repository's base class)

```
public IEnumerable<SomeDomainObject> GetMyDomainObjects()
{
    var query = "select abc from xyz where foo = ?";
    var command = _dal.CreateCommand(query);
    var reader = _dal.QueryReader(command);

    if (reader.HasRows)  // fails here if I close connection in QueryReader()
    {
        var list = new IList<MyDomainObject>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // build the domain object and append it to the list
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // error handling here
    }
}
```

Note: The crashes occurred because I didn't have the try/finally to close the connection as early as possible, so I've added them in since then. But now the finally clause closes the connection underlying the `OdbcDataReader` so that when the reader is being processed by the domain, it can't read any data because the connection is closed.

ISSUE: If I close the connection in the DAL then it is closed before the reader can iterate. Should I manually open and close the connection in each repository method, i.e. inside `GetMyDomainObjects` should I open the connection (via `_dal.GetConnection()`) and then have a `try/finally` that will close the connection? In every repository method? Or is there a way to manage this connection centrally, i.e. via IDispose on the DAL, and then just dispose of the DAL itself at the end of the method instead of exposing the underlying connection to the repository method?

Any and all help much appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit**

Here is the error message that is coming up in the ELMAH log:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

Also, this application is replacing an old legacy classic ASP site that connects to the same database. When I roll back to the legacy site the database connection works correctly. So it isn't the Oracle connection itself I don't think.

Comment: I think you might want to use the using statement and you need not close the connection manually each time,the dispose method which is already been implemented by OdbcConnection will take of closing.Ideally you might want to have something like Using(var objdal = new  yourdal){ // do operation.}

Comment: @restless Thanks. So you mean that I should add a using statement into each of my repositories, every time they touch the DAL? If so then I would need to implement IDispose on the DAL which I haven't done yet. Is that correct?

Comment: Just to clarify, the DAL != the connection, so I still have to deal with closing the connection.

Comment: In cases like this (though not in Oracle) I have used [CommandBehavior.CloseConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) when calling `ExecuteReader` - "When the command is executed, the associated Connection object is closed when the associated DataReader object is closed."

Comment: @stuartd ooh that is interesting, will check that out.

Comment: @Dave Yes,you must implement the dispose method in repository and in the dispose method you call connection.Dispose().

Comment: You should always close connections, especially with web

Comment: @stuartd I tried that and I'm getting the same error message once again after a few minutes of actual load.

Comment: @stuartd I just updated the question to include the error message. 40 of them within ten minutes. :(

Comment: @Dave note that **the associated Connection object is closed when the associated DataReader object is closed.** - you need to explicitly close your data readers after use, and make sure that's the only thing that closes the connection.

Comment: @stuartd They should all be closed manually already at the end of each repository method, but I'll go through and check them all.

Comment: @Dave I mentioned it as the reader wasn't closed in your example `GetMyDomainObjects`

Comment: @stuartd That was just an example but you are correct, I am finding some of the ones hit the hardest have readers that weren't closed after building the domain objects and collections. Patching those now, will see if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your second function definition as follows:

```
public OdbcDataReader QueryReader(OdbcCommand command)
{
    var connection = GetConnection();
    connection.Open;
    try
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Prepare();
        return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    finally
    {
        //connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I believe the solution is self explanatory.

Comment: I would take it a step further and just use `using (var connection = GetConnection())` to wrap the commands.

Comment: Would wrapping the connection `using()` in the `QueryReader()` methods prevent the `OdbcDataReader` from iterating the resultset after the call to `QueryReader` has completed? I recall getting errors in Entity Framework in cases like that but not sure about the `OdbcDataReader`. Thanks.

Comment: "I believe the solution is self explanatory" sounds like either "I don't actually understand how this works" or "I can't be bothered to explain this, or even provide a link to the documentation"

Comment: This isn't entirly going to fix the issue. Using CommandBehavior.CloseConnection closes the connection when the DataReader is closed. As the Repository in the question does not close the reader  in a using or try/finally the connection will still not get closed in the event of a crash.

Comment: @MartinBrown If I understand you correctly you are saying that the DAL methods like `QueryReader(OdbcCommand command)` should close the `command.Connection` object in the `catch` block, to ensure the connection is closed if the reader cannot execute? Or do you mean a `try/catch` in each repository method that accesses the DAL? The former is an edit in a couple of places, the latter is in dozens. Just trying to make sure I understand you. Thanks.

Comment: I mean that the "var reader = _dal.QueryReader(command);" line in your repository classes should be in a using statement like this "using (var reader = _dal.QueryReader(command)) { while (reader.Read()) { // ... } }". Once that is done, implement the DAL as this answer has suggested.

Comment: Ok I see. So then there would be no need to manually close the reader in each repository method, because the reader would automatically close when it goes out of scope thanks to the `using`, which would require `IDispose` on the DAL, correct? But `IDispose` will fire when the DAL class as a whole goes out of scope, so how does it ensure the connection opened as a local variable in a method such as `QueryReader` is closed?

Comment: @MartinBrown, my bad, I didn't see that the `reader` was not closed.. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: @stuartd, I didn't mean either of the two.. I seriously believe that the parameter added would suffice its purpose..

Comment: You are correct, adding that parameter and tracking down the readers that weren't closed did the trick. There were a few places where multistep operations were performed with reads and writes across multiple tables in a transaction and I had to make sure the readers were closed properly in each branch in the logic. (i.e. to catch errors etc) That plus a few structural changes to the DAL did the trick. The site is rock solid now. Thanks!